# Firestore throws NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore

I try to implement and test the example code from google page https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/create-database-server-client-library

so I use the dependency:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>google-cloud-firestore</artifactId>
     <version>3.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

an my code is:

```
FirestoreOptions firestoreOptions =
    FirestoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().toBuilder()
        .setProjectId(projectId)
        .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault())
        .build();
Firestore db = firestoreOptions.getService(); // <--- Exceptions
```

Than I just received the exception:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/grpc/internal/ManagedChannelImplBuilder$ChannelBuilderDefaultPortProvider

It seems like the need an additional dependency, so I thought maybe the admin dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
    <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

but nothing changed.
I also use the firebase admin and when I check the dependency I see the firebase admin use the the same library io gprc.

my mvn tree:

```
[INFO] --- dependency:3.6.0:tree (default-cli) @ alpha-editor ---
[INFO] test.project.alpha:alpha-editor:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- io.vertx:vertx-health-check:jar:4.3.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.vertx:vertx-core:jar:4.3.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.86.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.86.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.86.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.86.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.86.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.86.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.86.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.86.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.86.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.86.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.86.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns:jar:4.1.86.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-dns:jar:4.1.86.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.vertx:vertx-web:jar:4.3.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.vertx:vertx-web-common:jar:4.3.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.vertx:vertx-bridge-common:jar:4.3.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.vertx:vertx-auth-common:jar:4.3.7:compile
[INFO] +- io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:jar:0.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] +- test.project:core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.24:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jetbrains:annotations:jar:23.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- one.microstream:microstream-storage-embedded:jar:08.01.01-MS-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- one.microstream:microstream-storage:jar:08.01.01-MS-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- one.microstream:microstream-afs-nio:jar:08.01.01-MS-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- one.microstream:microstream-persistence-binary:jar:08.01.01-MS-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- one.microstream:microstream-persistence:jar:08.01.01-MS-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- one.microstream:microstream-storage-embedded-configuration:jar:08.01.01-MS-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- one.microstream:microstream-configuration:jar:08.01.01-MS-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- one.microstream:microstream-base:jar:08.01.01-MS-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- one.microstream:microstream-afs-googlecloud-firestore:jar:08.01.01-MS-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-firestore:jar:3.0.17:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core-grpc:jar:2.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.android:annotations:jar:4.1.1.4:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.15:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.opencensus:opencensus-contrib-http-util:jar:0.31.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-cloud-firestore-v1:jar:3.0.17:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.cloud:proto-google-cloud-firestore-bundle-v1:jar:3.0.17:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.opencensus:opencensus-contrib-grpc-util:jar:0.31.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:jar:1.44.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:jar:1.44.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.grpc:grpc-context:jar:1.44.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.19.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.api:gax:jar:2.12.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.api:gax-grpc:jar:2.12.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.grpc:grpc-alts:jar:1.44.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.grpc:grpc-grpclb:jar:1.44.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.conscrypt:conscrypt-openjdk-uber:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.grpc:grpc-auth:jar:1.44.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:jar:1.44.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.grpc:grpc-xds:jar:1.44.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.grpc:grpc-services:jar:1.44.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.re2j:re2j:jar:1.5:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.67:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.67:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.opencensus:opencensus-proto:jar:0.2.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:3.21.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.threeten:threetenbp:jar:1.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.grpc:grpc-stub:jar:1.44.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.opencensus:opencensus-api:jar:0.31.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.auth:google-auth-library-credentials:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core:jar:2.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-iam-v1:jar:1.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:jar:1.41.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:jar:3.19.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- one.microstream:microstream-afs-blobstore:jar:08.01.01-MS-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- one.microstream:microstream-afs:jar:08.01.01-MS-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.4.0-b180830.0359:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.19.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.19.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.19.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- io.vertx:vertx-hazelcast:jar:4.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.hazelcast:hazelcast:jar:4.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:jar:9.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.api-client:google-api-client:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:jar:1.34.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-apache-v2:jar:1.42.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.43.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.api:api-common:jar:2.12.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:jar:1.17.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:jar:2.22.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:jar:1.43.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:jar:v1-rev20230301-2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core-http:jar:2.19.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-appengine:jar:1.43.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.api:gax-httpjson:jar:0.114.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-cloud-storage-v2:jar:2.22.4-alpha:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.api.grpc:grpc-google-cloud-storage-v2:jar:2.22.4-alpha:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.api.grpc:gapic-google-cloud-storage-v2:jar:2.22.4-alpha:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.grpc:grpc-googleapis:jar:1.55.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.grpc:grpc-rls:jar:1.55.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:31.1-jre:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:jar:1.30.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:1.30.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- io.grpc:grpc-api:jar:1.30.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.13.0:runtime
[INFO] |     +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.3.4:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.perfmark:perfmark-api:jar:0.19.0:runtime
[INFO] |     +- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.18:runtime
[INFO] |     \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.12.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.testng:testng:jar:7.7.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.beust:jcommander:jar:1.82:test
[INFO] |  \- org.webjars:jquery:jar:3.6.1:test
[INFO] +- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.31:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-csv:jar:1.9.0:compile
[INFO] +- io.vertx:vertx-junit5:jar:4.3.7:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.8.2:test
[INFO] |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.8.2:test
[INFO] +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.7.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.7.0:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:5.4.0:test
[INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.14.5:test
[INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.14.5:test
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.3:test
[INFO] \- org.javatuples:javatuples:jar:1.2:compile
```

Does someone knows why I receive the exceptions?

Comment: It appears that you are using the `grpc` dependency, which is incompatible with the version used by `google-cloud-firestore`. You can inspect the dependency tree using `mvn dependency:tree` and consider upgrading to a newer version of `google-cloud-firestore`. Otherwise, if `grpc` is included as a transitive dependency from another library, you may try exclude it, or if you are using `grpc` as a direct dependency, ensure it has a compatible version with `google-cloud-firestore`.

Comment: Firebase Admin is just a wrapper around (and depends upon) Google Cloud libraries.  It's never a dependency.

Comment: @rdiachenko I add the tree, but i don't know which library I have to exclude.

Comment: @Qeychon, please check this [dependency](https://github.com/googleapis/java-firestore/tree/main#quickstart:~:text=%3E%0A%20%20%3C/dependency%3E-,If,-you%20are%20using) if you are using Maven without the BOM.

Comment: @RobertG I use a Plugin to analyze the maven dependency conflicts, so I exclude from a dependency io.grpc:grpc now it works. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Posting as a community wiki based on @Qeychon's comment:

> I use a Plugin to analyze the maven dependency conflicts, so I exclude from a dependency `io.grpc:grpc`, now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your dependencies are causing downgrades of dependencies. There is a mix of 1.55.1, 1.44.1, 1.30.2, but the 1.30.2 is for grpc-core which is used by the packages that are at 1.55.1.

It is not generally safe to downgrade dependencies. Enable Maven Enforcer's requireUpperBoundDeps:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <requireUpperBoundDeps/>
              </rules>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Then, for any failures it finds during the build, add an explicit dependency to your build to force Maven to use the newer version. Sometimes reordering your dependencies can reduce the number of failures, putting newer dependencies at nearer the top.